# If I build using iOS7 SDK, will my app have the new look on older devices?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6

I'm finally updating my iOS app to build with Xcode 5 and iOS7 SDK.  I see this gives my app a new look (white, no border on buttons, etc).  I don't have iOS6 available for easy testing, so I'm asking here.

**Will my app have the new look when run on older devices, or still the old look?**

I hope it doesn't have a different look on different devices, that will be a pain to design for (i.e.-make sure buttons/colors/spacing/etc are all optimized for each look).  I do notice a lot of apps don't use many "native" elements like toolbars, tab strips, or native buttons, maybe this is why (keep the same look across all OS versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using stock UI elements (provided by the Apple SDK), then on iOS 7 it will have the new look (iOS 7 look), and on iOS 6 it will have the old look (iOS 6 look).

While the colors / look may be a little different, the spacing shouldn't be too different.

If you wan't it to look the same on all OS versions, just use your own custom buttons etc, or customise the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks, luckily I only have 1 iOS app, so glad I learned early... will not use native look when I redesign.  Main difference is the border around buttons, 4 "all text" buttons next to each other looked fine before, now it just runs together.  I also had buttons beside input fields, but now they just look like labels, not buttons.